# Don't watch my log file for changes in Streamlit

Tags: logging, streamlit

I added logging to a file for the Streamlit app I'm using on my local machine by running the following command line in linux:

```
streamlit run main.py --logger.level=debug 2> >(tee -a main.log >&2)
```

However, when I do this, streamlit starts producing a LOT of debug messages like the ones below (I stopped the process as quickly as I could, but it still produced a log file 700k in size):

```
2023-03-18 06:47:50.800 Server started on port 8501
2023-03-18 06:47:50.802 Runtime state: RuntimeState.INITIAL -> RuntimeState.NO_SESSIONS_CONNECTED
2023-03-18 06:47:50.804 in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/llm/main.log', wd=1, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name='main.log'>
2023-03-18 06:47:50.804 in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/llm/main.log', wd=1, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name='main.log'>
2023-03-18 06:47:50.805 in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/llm/main.log', wd=1, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name='main.log'>
2023-03-18 06:47:50.806 in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/llm/main.log', wd=1, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name='main.log'>
2023-03-18 06:47:50.807 Ignoring changed path /llm/main.log.
```

Is there a way to get Streamlit's watcher to ignore main.log?  My workaround is to log to a different path at this stage.

(Tangentially, I don't see why I have to redirect output, setting the log file inside the main.py doesn't work)

```
# has no effect in streamlit
import logging

logname='main.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=logname,filemode='a',level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I tried adding the following to `config.toml`, but still got the large amount of debug messages:

```
[server]
folderWatchBlacklist = ["log"]
```

I guess this is to be expected, as streamlit developers need to see what their code is doing, but I want to see the debug message from my code, not streamlit's code ;).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Streamlit uses the default logging for debug messages. One solution could be to define a child logger for example `logging.getLogger(__name__)` instead of root logger by default. Here’s an article on [Python Logging Basics](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/python-logging-basics/) that might help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and our solution is similar to the one from Yan Liu by circumventing the root logger.

But to be able to configure one logger that works across all the modules we defined our own with a specific name in a separate function. This one get's called at the login page of our streamlit app (or just your first page or entry point).

```py
import logging, datetime, os
import streamlit as st
from pathlib import Path
    
@st.cache_resource
def setup_logging():
"""
creates specific logger 'my_logger' as streamlit occupies 
the root logger with heavy logging traffic.
"""

    logging_path = Path(os.getenv('LOGGING_PATH'))
    if not os.path.exists(logging_path):
        os.makedirs(logging_path)

    timestamp = dt.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")
    log_file = logging_path / f'{timestamp}.log'

    logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-5s]: %(message)s [%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]")

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

And then wherever in your code you want to do some logging, just get the logger at the top via:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
...
logger.debug("This is a debug log message")
```

Obviously, "my_logger" should be replaced with a meaningful name.